# How does gunicorn deploy django better?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I am using nginx with gunicorn and django. I would like to know

Question: What are the benefits using gunicorn compared to just using django's runserver alone

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver

> `django-admin runserver [addrport]`
>
> Starts a lightweight development Web server on the local machine.
>
> ...
>
> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone
>   through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s
>   gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web
>   servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production
>   environment is outside the scope of Django.)

Also Gunicorn can create multiple workers listening to the same socket which makes the web-app serve HTTP requests in parallel.